SimpleInjector: how to register proxy class for several interfaces at once
I'm developing a Telegram bot. And I'm struggling with SimpleInjector class registration.
I need to register a class ProxyBotMesssageSender  as a proxy for BotMesssageSender class that implements 3 interfaces: IMessageSender,IMessageForwarder,IMessageCopier
The whole structure:
//Provides sending of new messages
public interface IMessageSender{
  IObservable<Message> ObservableSend(SendMessage message);
  IObservable<Message> ObservableSend(MessageBuilder messageBuilder);
}

//Provides forwarding of existing messages
public interface IMessageForwarder{
  IObservable<Message> Forward(ForwardMessage message);
  IObservable<MessageIdObject[]> Forward(ForwardMessages messages);
}

//Provides copying of existing messages
public interface IMessageCopier{
  IObservable<MessageIdObject> Copy(CopyMessage message);
  IObservable<MessageIdObject[]> Copy(CopyMessages messages);
}

//Wrapper for third party library
public class BotMesssageSender : IMessageSender, IMessageForwarder, IMessageCopier{
    public BotMesssageSender(TelegramBot bot)
    {
      this.bot = bot;
    }
...
}

//Proxy that provides processing of sending limits
//It creates inner disposable object that provides information 
//for the class when it's allowed to send next message
public class ProxyBotMesssageSender : AbstractBotMessageSender, IMessageSender, IMessageForwarder, IMessageCopier, IDisposable{

  public BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(IMessageSender sender, IMessageCopier messageCopier, IMessageForwarder messageForwarder)
  {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.messageCopier = messageCopier;
    this.messageForwarder = messageForwarder;
...
  }
}

My current registration instructions:
  public override void Install()
  {
    Container.Register<IMessageSender,BotMesssageSender>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    Container.Register<IMessageForwarder,BotMesssageSender>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    Container.Register<IMessageCopier,BotMesssageSender>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    
    Container.RegisterDecorator<IMessageSender,BotMessageSenderTimerProxy>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    Container.RegisterDecorator<IMessageForwarder,BotMessageSenderTimerProxy>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    Container.RegisterDecorator<IMessageCopier,BotMessageSenderTimerProxy>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
...
    }


But as I expected, the injector tries to decorate each interface one by one.
Is it possible to register proxy somehow, that injector will apply it as a decorator for the interfaces without breaking the DI principle?

Update for @Steven
void Method(){
  var telegramBot = new TelegramBot();
  var sender = new BotMesssageSender(telegramBot);
  var generalSender = new BotMessageSenderProxy(sender, sender, sender);
  IMessageSender messageSender = generalSender;
  IMessageCopier messageCopier = generalSender;
  IMessageForwarder messageForwarder = generalSender;
} 


Can you show in code what exact object structure you wish to build? Simplest way to demonstrate this is writing the code with all the new statements as if there is no DI Container, e.g. new ProxyBotMesssageSender(new BotMesssageSender(..)) etc.

Sure. I updated my question.

You are trying to use BotMessageSenderProxy as a decorator, while it doesn't fit Simple Injector's definition of a decorator. This is because you are trying to register BotMessageSenderProxy as decorator for three interfaces, while, from Simple Injector's perspective, a decorator class should only be used to decorate on specific interface.
In your current design and registration, that would lead to a cyclic dependency, as the other two interfaces would receive the decorator as well. This is what the object graph would look like when resolving the IMessageSender:
var bot = new TelegramBot();
var botSender = new BotMesssageSender(bot);
IMessageSender sender =
    new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
        sender: botSender,
        copier: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
            sender: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
                sender: botSender,
                copier: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
                    sender: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
                        sender: botSender,
                        copier: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
                            sender: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
                                sender: botSender,
                                copier: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
                                    sender: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(
                                        sender: botSender,
                                        copier: new BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(...),
                                        ...                                    

As this dependency graph is cyclic, it has no end. It would go on in depth forever. That that's clearly not a pursuable goal.
Instead, I suggest changing your BotMessageSenderTimerProxy into a proxy on merely the BotMesssageSender. In other words, change its definition to the following:
public class ProxyBotMesssageSender : AbstractBotMessageSender
   , IMessageSender, IMessageForwarder, IMessageCopier, IDisposable
{
  public BotMessageSenderTimerProxy(BotMesssageSender sender)
  {
    this.sender = sender;
  }
  ...
}

When you do this, you can change your registrations to the following:
Container.Register<TelegramBot>();
Container.Register<BotMesssageSender>();
Container.Register<IMessageSender, BotMessageSenderProxy>();
Container.Register<IMessageCopier, BotMessageSenderProxy>();
Container.Register<IMessageForwarder, BotMessageSenderProxy>();

This construct the following object graphs:
var bot = new TelegramBot();
var botSender = new BotMesssageSender(bot);
var proxy = new BotMessageSenderProxy(botSender);

IMessageSender sender = proxy;
IMessageCopier copier = proxy;
IMessageForwarder forwarder = proxy;

